# How to change the value with a select in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, alias

I need to have an other value instead of FULL and NONE but I must do it in the select.

```
SELECT Calendar_Month,Series,Cnt 
FROM T_Cust_Eom_n 
where TYP='REB'
  and Series='FULL' 
   or TYP='REB' 
  and Series='NONE'  
order by Series desc,Calendar_Month
```

Can I do this with an as anyhow?

Comment: i am not cleared with your question, but i guess you can user case when.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want:

```
SELECT Calendar_Month,
CASE WHEN Series = 'FULL'
    THEN 'YOUR_TEXT_FOR_FULL'
     WHEN Series = 'NONE'
    THEN 'YOUR_TEXT_FOR_NONE'
END
AS Series
,Cnt
FROM T_Cust_Eom_n 
WHERE (TYP='REB'and Series='FULL') OR (TYP='REB' and Series='NONE')  ORDER BY Series DESC,Calendar_Month
```

Comment: Is it also possible to directly write it inside the column series and don't make a new column?

Comment: Yups. I missed that series is already used. Please find above my edited answer.

Comment: @fusionchart_help - Please vote and  mark it as Answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

You should use `()` when you have multiple conditions in `WHERE` clause.

**Solution:**

Improved your query with `IN`. You can use any other values inside the `()`:

```
SELECT Calendar_Month,Series,Cnt 
FROM T_Cust_Eom_n 
where TYP='REB' 
  and Series IN ('FULL','NONE', 'ANOTHER_VALUE')
order by Series desc,Calendar_Month
```